# Growing line underneath on selected items menu wp

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I've added a CSS code dding a line that appears to grow from left to right directly beneath the menu item being hovered over. It will also set a static line directly beneath the active page link. I want to know if is possible to exclude the Instagram Icon link, and make the CSS work only on the other menu items.

This is my CSS code:

```css
#top-menu .current-menu-item a::before,
#top-menu .current_page_item a::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li a:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -2;
 left: 0;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: 50%;
 background: #94812b;
 height: 2px; 
 -webkit-transition-property: right;
 transition-property: right;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#top-menu li a:hover {
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
#top-menu li a:hover:before {
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li li a:before {
 bottom: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Can you add HTML as well, so we know what we are working with?

Comment: You could look into css pseudo class :not.